# If condition and forloop

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

My algorithm is divided into two stages:

(1)Forloop,(2) if condtion

I got error in my following script is:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \caption{Pseudo-code }
        \Input{ X}
        \Output{Y}
        \ForEach {$X \in \mathcal Y$}{

            $Z \gets \text U$\;
        }
        $T \gets R$\;
        \If {$T\geq G$}
        \State $T\gets 0$
        \Else
        \State $T\gets 1$
        \EndIf
    \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wouldn't mix `algorithmic` and `algorithm2e`. the following works fine:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Pseudo-code}
%    \begin{algorithmic}
        \Input{X}
        \Output{Y}
        \ForEach {$X \in \mathcal{Y}$}{
                  $Z \gets \mathrm{U}$\;
        }
        $T \gets R$\;
        \eIf {$T \geq G$}{
              $T\gets 0$\;
        }{
             $T\gets 1$\;
        }
%    \end{algorithmic}
        \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]